# With wagmi and next.js, how to call useContractReads in getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to get some data onchain with useContractReads in getServerSideProps

```js
import React from "react"

import {
    useContractReads,
} from 'wagmi'

import { ProjectContractAddress, ProjectContractAbi } from '../constants'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const contract = {
        addressOrName: ProjectContractAddress,
        contractInterface: ProjectContractAbi,
        functionName: 'proposalCount'
    }
    const { data, isError, isLoading, isSuccess } = useContractReads({
        contracts: [
            contract,
        ],
    })
    result = data?.toString() ?? undefined
    return {
        props: { result }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
}


export default function AllProjects({ result }) {
(...)
```

brower tells me "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')"
when the server console tells me "Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: (...)"

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The `getServerSideProps` function runs on the server, you can't use React hooks inside  it. Hooks can only be used in React components or other custom hooks in client-side code. If you want to use that hook you'll have to move it inside the `AllProjects` component.

Comment: I don't know if it change something ,but I noticed that there is a extra " , " in your import
i think it should be 
    import {
        useContractReads
    } from 'wagmi'
instead of 

    import {
        useContractReads,
    } from 'wagmi'

Answer (score 3):

As juliomalves mentioned, you cannot use hooks in the getServerSideProps. However you can use [readContract](https://wagmi.sh/core/actions/readContract) in the **wagmi-core** to get on chain data without using a hook.